# Search from specific to general from large ruleset

Tags: php, database, algorithm, filter

I have a table that stores price of products in that is hierarchically organized from country level to store level.

```
create table price_list(
product_id number,
country_id number,
region_id number,
store_id number,
price number
)
```

I need to search this table to generate invoice. The input for the function (not elaborated here) is in this pattern (i'll use json structure to explain):

```
{
    header : {country_id:5, region_id:234, store_id:345},
    items : {
       0:{product_id:1001, quantity:5}, 
       1:{product_id:299, quantity:1} 
       //, etc... 
      }
}
```

I want to get the price for the products specific to that store's setup.

Of course if every field is filled, I can search the price by using the complete select syntax.

```
select price from price_list where product_id = ? and country_id = ? and region_id = ? and store_id = ?
```

But there are cases where the fields in the table are incomplete, for example only the country_id and product_id is filled because the price is the same for that product in all regions and stores in that country. Let's say I don't want to populate all data with complete fields because of non-technical reasons. A sample data in the table is shown below.

```
product_id    country_id    region_id    store_id    price
1001          3             93           112         15
1001          3             93           113         15.5
1001          4             179                      14
1001          4             185                      13
1001          5                                      20
1001          5             999          999         25
```

Let's take an example if I want to execute this request

```
{
    header : {country_id:5, region_id:300, store_id:500},
    items : {
       0:{product_id:1001, quantity:5}, 
    }
}
```

This query will not return a result because country 5 does not specify specific price for each region and store except for region 999 store 999.

```
select price from price_list where product_id = 1001 and country_id = 5 and region_id = 300 and store_id = 500
```

Because no row is returned, I need to generalize the search, I start with using all fields, reducing one by one if no price is found.

```
where product_id = 1001 and country_id = 5 and region_id = 300
```

But still, this will not return any row. Then I generalized more, and this search gets the value.

```
where product_id = 1001 and country_id = 5
```

My current solution is exhaustive. Is there a better way to do this efficiently? The environment is Oracle 11g on php 5.4 and CodeIgniter2.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a variable which holds the where clause:

```
$priceWhereclause = "";
$params = [];

if(isset($productIdValue)){
   $priceWhereclause .= "product_id = ? ";
   $params[] = $productIdValue;
}

if(isset($countryIdValue)){
   $priceWhereclause .= "and country_id= ? ";
   $params[] = $countryIdValue;
}
```

Your query would look like:

`select price from price_list where $priceWhereclause`

put the `$params` in the `execute($params)` function.

Comment: I'm sorry for being not clear, I have updated my question. I think the problem is not in the query because all the values are always set in the request. The problem is how the search should be approached. 

For example if I have product 1001 for country 5 region 999 and store 1000, I can't put `where product_id = 1001 and country_id = 5 and region_id = 999 and store_id = 1000`. 

It will only work with `where product_id = 1001 and country_id = 5`

Comment: Wrap it around `(country_id = 5 AND store_id = 100) OR (country_id = 6 AND store_id = 110)`

Comment: i got a suggestion elsewhere using `SELECT price FROM price_list WHERE product_id = ? AND (country_id = ? OR country_id IS NULL) AND ... ORDER BY country_id ASC NULLS LAST, ...`